# Quasar font icons in css

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

Can I use my iconSet in css with `background-image` property?

My quasar.config properties:

```
       extras: ["material-icons-outlined"],
       framework: {
         iconSet: "material-icons-outlined",
       }.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is to add a font in your main css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v55/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) format('woff2')
 }
```

Then in your code you can access this your icon with specific code, e.g. `content: "\e145";`
The list of Material icon codes could be find [here](https://gist.github.com/loicbisiere/31f3ee50337e305f02564ab2c67a72fa)